# How to identify calling method from a called method in swift

Tags: ios, swift

here is a scenario

```
func callingMethod_A {
  self.someCalculation()
}

func callingMethod_B{
  self.someCalculation()
}

func someCalculation{
//how to find who called this method? is it callingMethod_A or _B at runtime?
//bla bla
}
```

how can we get the method name that called it during run time. 
thank you.

Comment: pass the argument to identify the method

Comment: Add argument, or if it's just for debug purpose, look at the callstack.

Comment: Larme, how do you look at the call stack in code? Is there a way to get the function signature from the call stack?

Comment: While passing the "caller ID" into a method works, there may well be a better way (delegate, return) to accomplish what you want. Why does `someCalculation` need to know if `callingMethod_A` or `callingMethod_B` called it? What happens when you decide to add `callingMethod_C` or change `callingMethod_A` to be callingMethod_A1`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I worked out a way to do this, for Swift code anyway:

Define a `String` parameter `callingFunction` and give it a default value of `#function`. Do not pass anything from the caller and the compiler provides the calling function name.

Building on @Anu.Krthik's answer:

```
func someCalculation (parameter: String, callingMethod: String = #function ) {
 print("In `\(#function)`, called by `\(callingMethod)`")
}

func foo(string: String) {
    someCalculation(parameter: string)
}

foo(string: "bar")
```

The above prints

```
In `someCalculation(parameter:callingMethod:)`, called by `foo(string:)`
```

However, beware that this technique can be subverted if the caller provides a value for the `callingFunction` parameter. if you call it with:

```
func foo(string: String) {
    someCalculation(parameter: string, callingMethod: "bogusFunctionName()")
}
```

You get the output

```
In `someCalculation(parameter:callingMethod:)`, called by `bogusFunctionName()`
```

instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Thread.callStackSymbols like this

```
func callingMethod_A() {
    self.someCalculation()
}

func callingMethod_B(){
    self.someCalculation()
}

func someCalculation(){
    let origin = Thread.callStackSymbols
    print(origin[0])
    print(origin[1])
}
```