# Discover where function was called

Tags: ios, swift

Is there a way when creating an iOS app using Swift to discover where a certain function was called, using code within that function?

Like so:

```
func someFunction(callee: Any) {

    print(callee)

    let localCallee = ...

    print(localCallee)

    print(#fileID)

}
```

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53208339/5133585) what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

As described in [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53208758/205185), you can add a parameter `callingFunction` to your function, with a default value of `#function`. The compiler then pre-populates that parameter with the signature of the calling function.

That will give you information about the caller at runtime.

If you want to see who’s calling your function at compile-time, you can also mark your function as deprecated and then compile your app. The compiler will then generate deprecation warnings at every location where that function is called. (This won’t work if your function is an implementation of a standard function like `viewDidLoad()`.)